# I deleted my files with git rm, but i also commited them, how to get them back?

Tags: linux, git, rm, restore, intellij

I ran git rm on some files thinking that they will be removed from the bitbucket repository, and i also commited them, after that i checked that they disapeared from the bitbucket repo, but they were deleted from my computer too.

here are the commands that I used :

```
$ git rm -r -f src

rm 'src/main/java/Controller.java'

rm 'src/main/java/DTO.java'

rm 'src/main/java/Scheduler.java'

rm 'src/main/java/Server.java'

rm 'src/main/java/SimulationManager.java'

rm 'src/main/java/SimulatorFrame.java'

rm 'src/main/java/Task.java'


$ git rm -f -r target

rm 'target/classes/Controller$1.class'

rm 'target/classes/Controller$startSimulationListener.class'

rm 'target/classes/Controller.class'

rm 'target/classes/DTO.class'

rm 'target/classes/Scheduler.class'

rm 'target/classes/Server.class'

rm 'target/classes/SimulationManager.class'

rm 'target/classes/SimulatorFrame.class'

rm 'target/classes/Task.class'


$ git rm -f pom.xml

rm 'pom.xml'


$ git rm -f pt2019_30222_tomoiaga_andreistefan_assignment_2.iml

fatal: pathspec 'pt2019_30222_tomoiaga_andreistefan_assignment_2.iml' did not match any files


$ git commit -m "delete commit"

[master a6c5d68] delete commit
 22 files changed, 1352 deletions(-)

 delete mode 100644 .idea/.name

 delete mode 100644 .idea/compiler.xml

 delete mode 100644 .idea/misc.xml

 delete mode 100644 .idea/vcs.xml

 delete mode 100644 .idea/workspace.xml

 delete mode 100644 pom.xml

 delete mode 100644 src/main/java/Controller.java

 delete mode 100644 src/main/java/DTO.java

 delete mode 100644 src/main/java/Scheduler.java

 delete mode 100644 src/main/java/Server.java

 delete mode 100644 src/main/java/SimulationManager.java

 delete mode 100644 src/main/java/SimulatorFrame.java

 delete mode 100644 src/main/java/Task.java

 delete mode 100644 target/classes/Controller$1.class

 delete mode 100644 target/classes/Controller$startSimulationListener.class

 delete mode 100644 target/classes/Controller.class

 delete mode 100644 target/classes/DTO.class

 delete mode 100644 target/classes/Scheduler.class

 delete mode 100644 target/classes/Server.class

 delete mode 100644 target/classes/SimulationManager.class

 delete mode 100644 target/classes/SimulatorFrame.class

 delete mode 100644 target/classes/Task.class


$ git push origin master

Enumerating objects: 3, done.

Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.

Delta compression using up to 8 threads

Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.

Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 227 bytes | 227.00 KiB/s, done.

Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)

To https://bitbucket.org/andreistefantomoiaga/pt2019_30222_tomoiaga_andreistefan_assignment_2.git

   5ca3e67..a6c5d68  master -> master


$ git rm -f pt2019_30222_tomoiaga_andreistefan_assignment_2.iml

rm 'pt2019_30222_tomoiaga_andreistefan_assignment_2.iml'


$ git commit -m "delete commit"

[master 16ca832] delete commit

 1 file changed, 2 deletions(-)

 delete mode 100644 pt2019_30222_tomoiaga_andreistefan_assignment_2.iml


$ git rm -f pt2019_30222_tomoiaga_andreistefan_assignment_2.iml

fatal: pathspec 'pt2019_30222_tomoiaga_andreistefan_assignment_2.iml' did not match any files


$ git push origin master

Enumerating objects: 3, done.

Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.

Delta compression using up to 8 threads

Compressing objects: 100% (1/1), done.

Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 238 bytes | 238.00 KiB/s, done.

Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

To https://bitbucket.org/andreistefantomoiaga/pt2019_30222_tomoiaga_andreistefan_assignment_2.git
   a6c5d68..16ca832  master -> master

$ git reset HEAD \*

Unstaged changes after reset:
M       Documentatie/Documentatie.docx


$ git reset --hard
HEAD is now at 16ca832 delete commit


$ git rm

usage: git rm [<options>] [--] <file>...

    -n, --dry-run         dry run
    -q, --quiet           do not list removed files
    --cached              only remove from the index
    -f, --force           override the up-to-date check
    -r                    allow recursive removal
    --ignore-unmatch      exit with a zero status even if nothing matched


$ git reset

$ git reset HEAD
```

I need to restore my project, if it is possible, also I thought that i could restore it from Intellij but I have no idea how.

I want to restore expecially the src folder

Comment: I recommend to never use `-r` in cases like that or equivalent global commands in git, so that you control more clearly what is happening especially if not 100% sure of what goal you have and how git will behave. Or, have very good backups...

Answer (score 0):

Your files and local changes are gone.

You can now restore

- a previous git revision (without your local changes)
- from Intellij (if possible)
- from your target directory - do not run `mvn clean`
- from the JAR/WAR file of the last build/deployment and decompile .class files
- from a backup

Comment: how could I restore from target directory?

Comment: @user347067 That depends on your pom.xml and what was copied/modified during the build process. Have a look at the target folder and its subfolders and you'll see.